# How do I create a pom.xml to compile my Jenkins Pipeline shared libs?

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

A [Jenkins Pipeline Shared Library](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/) usually has the following directory structure:

```
(root)
+- src                     # Groovy source files
|   +- org
|       +- foo
|           +- Bar.groovy  # for org.foo.Bar class
+- vars
|   +- foo.groovy          # for global 'foo' variable
|   +- foo.txt             # help for 'foo' variable
+- resources               # resource files (external libraries only)
|   +- org
|       +- foo
|           +- bar.json    # static helper data for org.foo.Bar
```

These are grovvy files that use some code from the Jenkins libs. I'd like to be able to compile them all using maven, probably using [GMavenPlus](https://github.com/groovy/GMavenPlus) maven plugin, and defining some Jenkins libs as dependencies.

I want to compile then so I can validate the files before committing or uploading to Jenkins. I'd probably also give me better code completion while editing the files.

Can someone help me to create a pom.xml file that would compile it?

Comment: Can you please specify why do you want to compile them?

Comment: @snukone I edited the question to explain.

Comment: Ah ok, very nice idea! I never thought of that yet. What are you thinking about @szymon stepniaks solution? Gradle is also a nice build tool compared to maven. If you really need a mvn example i will try tomorrow.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest using Gradle instead of Maven. Below you can find a minimal `build.gradle` file that allows you to compile, test and package Jenkins shared library (and even install in Maven repository if you need to share it with a different project):

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
apply plugin: 'maven'


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        groovy {
            srcDirs = ['src', 'vars']
        }
        resources {
            srcDirs = ['resources']
        }
    }
    test {
        groovy {
            srcDirs = ['test']
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.cloudbees:groovy-cps:1.22'
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.12'

    // https://github.com/jenkinsci/JenkinsPipelineUnit
    testCompile 'com.lesfurets:jenkins-pipeline-unit:1.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml.enabled true
    }
}
```

This minimal `build.gradle` file uses `jenkins-pipeline-unit` - a unit testing framework for Jenkins pipelines. It's very handy and it makes life 10 times easier.

Alternatively, you can check the following Gradle template project for Jenkins Pipeline shared library - https://github.com/mkobit/jenkins-pipeline-shared-library-example It comes with many other features and it also helps to maintain your shared library project.

However, if you really need to use Maven for that, you might use the following `pom.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>jenkins-shared-library</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.cloudbees</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-cps</artifactId>
            <version>1.22</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.12</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lesfurets</groupId>
            <artifactId>jenkins-pipeline-unit</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>test/</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
                <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>addSources</goal>
                            <goal>addTestSources</goal>
                            <goal>generateStubs</goal>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>generateTestStubs</goal>
                            <goal>compileTests</goal>
                            <goal>removeStubs</goal>
                            <goal>removeTestStubs</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <sources>
                        <source>
                            <directory>${project.basedir}/src</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*.groovy</include>
                            </includes>
                        </source>
                        <source>
                            <directory>${project.basedir}/vars</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*.groovy</include>
                            </includes>
                        </source>
                    </sources>
                    <testSources>
                        <source>
                            <directory>${project.basedir}/test</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*.groovy</include>
                            </includes>
                        </source>
                    </testSources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                            <goal>test-jar-no-fork</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

This is more ore less an equivalent of the `build.gradle` file.

Answer (score 0):

My solution with Maven so far you can see in the following pom.xml. You can compile your source files with the command `mvn clean compile`. If you want to know whats in the source files and which project structure was used you can check: https://github.com/snukone/compile-jenkins-pipeline

If you have futher questions or ideas for improvements just let me know :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>bar</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>src</source>
                                <source>vars</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</compilerId>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                        <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
                        <version>2.9.2-01</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                        <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-batch</artifactId>
                        <version>2.5.6-01</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```